# At what tier should data be escaped to send to a database?

Tags: database, web-applications, escaping

I have an MVC web application, and I'm wondering where the best place to escape data to send to a database is: the controller or model. I can't think of any arguments toward either side. Is there an accepted place to escape data? If not, what are the pros and cons of escaping data in a given tier?

Comment: You escape data when you pass user input to your domain object factory

Comment: Explicitly escaping data is flawed. You should use parameterized queries so that escaping is unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **d**) None of the above

You should use parameters.

You should never need to escape data for a database.

You do need to escape output for HTML; that should be done in the view.

Comment: Beat me to it. Seems to be a pattern emerging!

Comment: Do you happen to know if PHP provides an implementation of parameterized querying?

Comment: @arxanas: Yes; look into PDO.

Comment: @Raynos: Wherever the URL is being generated, which is is usually in the view.  In general, you should not escape data in advance.  The internal storage and passing of data should be done as pure data; not as view-specialized data.  Performance concerns can override this  In particularly, it's frequently a good idea to store pre-processed Markdown in the DB (alongside the original)

Comment: So I've been doing it wrong this entire time? >.<
Thanks for the help!

Comment: @SLaks thanks for the suggestion of pre processing markdown. I'm recompiling markdown on every request!

Comment: @Raynos: Check your performance before changing it, but it may be a good idea.    I'm pretty sure StackOverflow does that.  If you have a full-text index, you should figure out what it should index.